# How to evaluate a string as a function with a function, and assign it to a variable?

Tags: r

I have an object `function1` which takes in another `function0`, and assign it to a variable:

```
val <- function1(function0)
```

I would like to wrap this into a string and then evaluate the assignment:

```
get(eval(paste0("val <- function1(function0)"))
```

but it says it `cannot find the object`. Is there a way to do this in R?

Comment: @Waldi that is a perfectly valid syntax. It might not be what OP intends (or what `function1` is designed for), but that's a different topic.

Comment: @Nicola, had in mind function with argument like `cos(sin)` isn't valid, but you're right, deleted my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
eval(parse(text = "val <- function1(function0)"))
get("val")
```

An example:

```
function0 <- function () "WhatIf"
function1 <- function (f) f()
eval(parse(text = "val <- function1(function0)"))
get("val")
```

Comment: had in mind function with argument like cos(sin) isn't valid, but you're right, deleted my comment, +1